# 18.04 - gnome How to disable automatic screen brightness

Tags: gnome, 18.04, brightness

I 've been searching around on the web about this problem but nothing seems to be working since I cannot see those menu options people are suggesting.

The problem is intense when for example I work with Intellij and scrolling up and down the brightness changes.

Is there an option / flag on a file that I can change because I cannot see anything on the menu. 
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have no answer, but I have this same problem. I switched IntelliJ to the High Contrast theme instead of using Darcula, I find the brightness switching to be less annoying with that theme. Still looking for the real answer.

Comment: same problem here, dell xps13(2019) ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Dell Laptop (XPS 13), you can go to the BIOS (press Delete/F2) and disable automatic brightness in the options. This helped me!